# Visiting Russia with a Peruvian passport that says "Place of birth: USA"

Tags: airports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, russia, peruvian-citizens

I would like to visit Russia soon. I am Peruvian and live in Peru but my place of birth is the United States.
Peruvians can enter Russia for up to 90 days visa free.

However, might they ask me to show my American passport as well given my place of birth? I have both passports but intend to enter with the Peruvian one.

Comment: Even if the countries are more or less de facto at war, it does not seem as if it is currently prohibited for US citizens to enter Russia. Being born in the USA is of course a strong indicator for you being a dual citizen if you try to enter with your Peruvian passport, but what exactly are you worried about if the Russian authorities finds out that you are also a US citizen?

Comment: I'd be worried about being denied entry for not having a visa on the US passport despite being allowed to enter on the Peruvian one.

Comment: If you present your Peruvian passport and enter Russia as a Peruvian citizen, it is irrelevant what other citizenships you have. (Whether it is smart and/or ethical to visit Russia during the Russian invasion of Ukraine is a separate question.)

Comment: There are issues such as the treatment of Brittney Griner who IMO appears to have been detained and jailed on somewhat spurious grounds in Russia, perhaps to use as a bargaining chip against the US government. Any US citizen, dual or otherwise, could be treated similarly, although Griner being higher-profile is a more valuable bargaining chip. I certainly wouldn't be confident to say a dual citizen is safe.

Answer (score 6):

I personally know of multiple people with multiple citizenships that were able to enter Russia using their "visa free" passport while having another that was not visa free.

I also know of some people who were born in Russia but are no longer Russian citizens - and they were able to enter with their foreign passports showing "Russia" as the place of birth with no questions asked whatsoever.

You shouldn't have any problem, and if by any chance you do because a border guard is ignorant - reach out to the Peruvian consulate and ask for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Use your  Peruvian passport as it gives you a wave for visa up to 90 day (I personally have not checked that for your country). US citizens will need a visa to entry Russia. At the point of entry to Russia it is does not matter where have you been born. Plan to use for entry Peruvian passport exclusively, it is not anybody business what are your affiliation with other countries .

Comment: Not true, some countries do block or restrict citizens from other countries even when they have multiple citizenships and travel on an allowed one.